# Why is trailing slash being removed from URL on a remote host?

Tags: php, url

my url's work in localhost with this code

```
    print "REQUEST_URI :".$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];print '<hr/>';
    print "site:".$site=str_replace('index.php','',$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);print '<hr/>';
    print "REQUEST_URI:". $REQUEST_URI=str_replace($site,'',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);print '<hr/>';
```

and resutls are

> REQUEST_URI :/manogham/admin/login
>
> site:/manogham/
>
> REQUEST_URI:admin/login

but in server results are defirents

> REQUEST_URI :/admin/login/
>
> site:/
>
> REQUEST_URI:adminlogin

/ are remove from url why !!!!

Comment: Probably because those are running two different web server application or because the configurations on each of those servers  are different. You should just make your routing system so that it can handle the optional trailing slash.

Comment: php version of server 5.6.3 and php version in my localhost 5.6

Comment: I specifically used the term "web server". As in apache, nginx, iss or lighttpd.

Answer (score 1):

On the server

```
print "site:".$site=str_replace('index.php','',$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);print '<hr/>';
```

is "/" as you can see on your results.
$site is then "/".
When you do

```
$REQUEST_URI=str_replace($site,'',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

you remove all $site ("/") from the REQUEST_URI
That's why there is no more / displayed

Comment: then what in localhost running with out any problem ?